# Check Date is within THIS_WEEK

Tags: apex, datetime, date

I have to check whether "mydate" is in within the current week or not.

```
DateTime mydate= DateTime.newInstance(Date.Today().Year(),obj.Birthdate.Month(),obj.Birthdate.Day());

if(mydate==THIS_WEEK){
      lstBirthday.add(obj);
}
```

This gives me - **Compile Error: Variable does not exist: THIS_WEEK**
so what should I use instead of THIS_WEEK.

Answer (score 5):

I believe THIS_WEEK can only be used as a filter in a query, instead you could convert both dates to the startOfWeek and compare the results.

```
Date myTodayDate = Date.today();
Date thisWeekStart = myTodayDate.toStartofWeek();

DateTime mydate= DateTime.newInstance(Date.Today().Year(),obj.Birthdate.Month(),obj.Birthdate.Day());

Date bdayWeekStart = myDate.toStartOfWeek();
if(bdayWeekStart==thisWeekStart){
      lstBirthday.add(obj);
}
```